# Win 8.1- My second monitor stop working after the boot

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, asus-laptop

I tried to use a screen (a TV actually) on my laptop, it worked for few seconds and then it's not recognized anymore after the bootup.

I tried to use another screen on my laptop and it worked well. I tried to use the first screen on my PS4 and it worked well. The HDMI cable works fine too. So I don't really understand what is not working....

My drivers are up to date, my laptop is an Asus ROG G551JM-CN102H, the graphics card is a GTX 860m, and the integrated gpu is intel HD graphics 4600.

Answer (score 0):

I have owned a the same lap top as you, except it was the JM model. Long story short the screen on the lap top stopped working after 2 weeks and I had to return it. I think there was a button that would split the screen. Do fn + f8 and maybe that will split the screen.

Comment: that lap top was how I learned how computer hardware worked. I did a lot of research on the computer you own. Without it, I would have never learned anything. Although it let me down.